# Labels don't activate associated fields when part of an animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Playing with web technologies, I developed a dice using just HTML and CSS (without JavaScript). It's a simple system: a series of radio buttons and labels that simulate the dice by changing their positioning (with `z-index`) so every time that you click on the dice, there's a "random" number.

This is a minimal version of the code:

```css
@keyframes changeOrder {
  from { z-index: 6;}
  to { z-index: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeOrder {
  from { z-index: 6; }
  to { z-index: 1; }
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
  animation: changeOrder 1.2s infinite;
}

label:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
label:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: -0.2s; }
label:nth-of-type(3) { animation-delay: -0.4s; }
label:nth-of-type(4) { animation-delay: -0.6s; }
label:nth-of-type(5) { animation-delay: -0.8s; }
label:nth-of-type(6) { animation-delay: -1.0s; }
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb1" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb2" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb3" value="3"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb4" value="4"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb5" value="5"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb6" value="6"/>
<label for="cb1">1</label>
<label for="cb2">2</label>
<label for="cb3">3</label>
<label for="cb4">4</label>
<label for="cb5">5</label>
<label for="cb6">6</label>
```

The problem happens when, even when the dice is *rolling*, it not always takes action when the `label` is clicked on, and the radio button associated to the `label` is not activated. Sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.

I thought it could be because of the animation I used, and (unsuccessfully) played with the times to see if that would fix the problem... but it basically remains the same. I noticed that if I extend the times, the issue "disappears" (i.e. changing the times to 3s and delays in 0.5s or higher). But if I do that, it is more predictable (the goal is not to make it perfect but at least simulate some pseudo-randomness).

Why could this be happening? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: If you slow down the animation, it works as expected.  I am afraid it might be a timing issue.  The animation seems to be too fast for detecting a mouse-click (mouse-down + mouse-up) within the 0.2 seconds (200ms) it is running.

Comment: @ochi thanks, I was editing to add a note on that. What I find interesting is that I see the radio button graying when clicking on the label, but it doesn't activate. It's like it "gains focus" without checking it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already noticed it, the issue is due to how fast the animation is. The changes is faster than the click because a click is two actions: `mousedown` and `mouseup` and both should be done on the same element.

Here is a better illustration of the issue where you can NEVER make the input checked by clicking on the labels:

```css
label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
}

label:active {
  background:red;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb2" value="2">
<label for="cb1">1</label>
<label for="cb2">2</label>
```

When clicking, the element  will be hidden and the `mouseup` will no more be on the same element thus the click event is not done. The same is happening with your example is some cases.

---

An Idea to fix this is to allow the click to end by making the clicked element on the top until the end of the click event.

Here is an idea where I rely on a pseudo element with a big `z-index` so I can keep the click event on the needed element. You can also make the animation faster!

```css
.container {
 position:relative;
}
label {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
  animation: changeOrder 0.6s infinite;
}
@keyframes changeOrder {
  from { z-index: 6;}
  to { z-index: 1; }
}
label:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
label:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: -0.1s; }
label:nth-of-type(3) { animation-delay: -0.2s; }
label:nth-of-type(4) { animation-delay: -0.3s; }
label:nth-of-type(5) { animation-delay: -0.4s; }
label:nth-of-type(6) { animation-delay: -0.5s; }

label:active {
  /*Mandatory to break the stacking context and allow 
   the pseudo element to be above everything*/
  position:static; 
  /*For illustration*/
  margin-left: 50px;
  background:red;
}

label:active::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb2" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb3" value="3">
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb4" value="4">
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb5" value="5">
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb6" value="6">
<div class="container"> 
 <label for="cb1">1</label>
 <label for="cb2">2</label>
 <label for="cb3">3</label>
 <label for="cb4">4</label>
 <label for="cb5">5</label>
 <label for="cb6">6</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a really ingenious way. It works as I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Before posting here, I had created a [cross post on Stack on Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/182866/250). If you want to reply there (in Spanish), or I'll translate this and share it as a wiki answer (referencing this post).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro fell free to answer it there ;) am not good in spanish :p

Comment: Ok, I will. Btw, I had fun with your challenges ;)

Comment: Long time no talk. I am writing a blog post about the game in which used a variation of this code, I am citing/linking your answer. Is it ok with you if I also put the name in the post? (something like "Temani Afif came up with an explanation and a solution" and a link to here)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Hi, yes sure no problem ;)

Comment: The article was published today, and it cites you (and this answer) as a reference: https://css-tricks.com/are-there-random-numbers-in-css/

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro good article, well written ;) by the way, I have released my website CSS Challenges (https://css-challenges.com/) if you are intrested in spending time solving some of them or even contributing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use `input:active` and `animation-play-state: paused`, like so:

```css
@keyframes changeOrder {
  from { z-index: 6;}
  to { z-index: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes changeOrder {
  from { z-index: 6; }
  to { z-index: 1; }
}

label {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  text-align: center;
  animation: changeOrder 1.2s infinite;
}

label:nth-of-type(1) { animation-delay: 0s; }
label:nth-of-type(2) { animation-delay: -0.2s; }
label:nth-of-type(3) { animation-delay: -0.4s; }
label:nth-of-type(4) { animation-delay: -0.6s; }
label:nth-of-type(5) { animation-delay: -0.8s; }
label:nth-of-type(6) { animation-delay: -1.0s; }

input:active ~ label {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb1" value="1"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb2" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb3" value="3"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb4" value="4"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb5" value="5"/>
<input type="radio" name="cb" id="cb6" value="6"/>
<label for="cb1">1</label>
<label for="cb2">2</label>
<label for="cb3">3</label>
<label for="cb4">4</label>
<label for="cb5">5</label>
<label for="cb6">6</label>
```

This works as the `input` actually receives the user's input from things like `:active` and `:hover` when the user does it on the corresponding `label`.