# HTML Label doesn't trigger the respective input if the mouse gets moved while clicking in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, label

In the following example, when you click on the label, the input changes state.

```js
document.querySelector("label").addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked label");
});
```

```css
label {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="1">
<label for="1">Label</label>
```

In Chrome, when you move the cursor between the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events the input still gets triggered, whereas in Firefox the checkbox doesn't change state.

Is there a way to fix this? (without using JavaScript event listeners)

Firefox version: `69.0.3 (64-bit)`

Full set of actions when using chrome.

1. Press the button over the label
2. Move the cursor around (even outside the label) while still holding the button
3. Return the cursor back to the label
4. Release the button

Comment: *In Chrome, when you move the cursor between the mousedown and mouseup events the input still gets triggered* --> it's not the case for me on chrome and ot shouldn't be. a click = mousedown+mouseup .. related for some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51451218/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif Is it the case for you on chrome now? (since I've clarified what it is that I'm doing). Or does it still not change the state of the checkbox?

Comment: If we keep the mouse over the label then it's ok. the move shouldn't affect this so I guess we are facing a Firefox bug

Comment: this is a bug which is loged as UNCONFIRMED status in firfox bug portal, "A "click" event should only occur if the mousedown and mouseup were in the same location"  you can check there bug url: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=319347

Comment: @AmitJadli thanks for digging this out. My answer ought to have included this but I couldn’t find it whilst I’m on my phone.

Comment: if you look closely you will notice that it's not related to the cursor being on the top or not but you will have the issue if you only move the cursor even if you are still on the top of the label. The movement is breaking it.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I agree, moving the cursor even `1px` will break the interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introduction

Although I specifically stated in the question that the answer shouldn't involve JavaScript, all the answers worked with JavaScript.
 
Since this seems to be a Firefox bug and most of the answers submitted at this point would require me to also alter the rest of my code, I decided to create a script that can be run once, will deal with all the labels regardless of when they are added to the dom and will have the least impact on my other scripts.

### Solution - Example

```js
var mutationConfiguration = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true
};

if (document.readyState === "complete") onLoad();
else addEventListener("load", onLoad);

var managingDoms = [];

function onLoad() {
  document.querySelectorAll("label[for]").forEach(manageLabel);
  if (typeof MutationObserver === "function") {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(list) {
      list.forEach(function(item) {
        ({
          "attributes": function() {
            if (!(item.target instanceof HTMLLabelElement)) return;
            if (item.attributeName === "for") manageLabel(item.target);
          },
          "childList": function() {
            item.addedNodes.forEach(function(newNode) {
              if (!(newNode instanceof HTMLLabelElement)) return;
              if (newNode.hasAttribute("for")) manageLabel(newNode);
            });
          }
        }[item.type])();
      });
    });
    observer.observe(document.body, mutationConfiguration);
  }
}

function manageLabel(label) {
  if (managingDoms.includes(label)) return;
  label.addEventListener("click", onLabelClick);
  managingDoms.push(label);
}

function onLabelClick(event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
  var id = this.getAttribute("for");
  var target = document.getElementById(id);
  if (target !== null) {
    this.removeAttribute("for");
    var self = this;
    target.click();
    target.focus();
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.setAttribute("for", id);
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

```css
label {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a">
<input type="text" id="b">
<label for="a">A</label>
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.setAttribute("for", "b");
    label.textContent = "b";
    document.body.appendChild(label);
  }, 3E3);
</script>
```

### Explanation

`onLabelClick`
The function `onLabelClick` needs to get called whenever a label gets clicked, it will check if the label has a corresponding input element. If it does, it will trigger it, remove the `for` attribute of the label so that the browsers don't have the bug won't re-trigger it and then use a `setTimeout` of `0ms` to add the `for` attribute back once the event has bubbled up. This means `event.preventDefault` doesn't have to get called and thus no other actions/events will get cancelled. Also if I need to override this function I just have to add an event-listener that calls `Event#preventDefault` or removes the `for` attribute.
`manageLabel`
The function `manageLabel` accepts a label checks if it has already been added an event listener to avoid re-adding it, adds the listener if it hasn't already been added, and adds it to the list of labels have been managed.
 `onLoad`
The function `onLoad` needs to get called when the page gets loaded so that the function `manageLabel` can be called for all the labels on the DOM at that moment. The function also uses a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to catch any labels that get added, after the load has been fired (and the script has been run).

The code displayed above was optimized by [Martin Barker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/623150/martin-barker).

Comment: You code is a little unoptimised doing some checks it does not need to and some costly CPU Cycles, i have optimised it for you at https://pastebin.com/FDXwQL1d

Comment: It does not remove the check it replaces it with `HTMLLabelElement` check instead of both an HTMLElement and a check that the tagName was a label

Comment: clever but massively overcomplicated

Answer (score 2):

I know you did not want JS Event listeners, but im thinking you mean to identify the movement this does not but is using mousedown instead of click (mousedown followed by mouseup).

While this is a known bug in Firefox you could get around it by using the [mousedown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event)

I have had to change your id to be a valid one id's must start with a character

```js
document.querySelector("label").addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
  console.log("clicked label");
  // if you want to to check the checkbox when it happens,
  let elmId = evt.target.getAttribute("for")
  let oldState = document.querySelector("#"+elmId).checked;
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(oldState == document.querySelector("#"+elmId).checked){
      document.querySelector("#"+elmId).checked = !oldState;
    }
  }, 150)
});
```

```css
label {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="valid_1">
<label for="valid_1">Label</label>
```

Comment: The problem is that I will have to run this script (using `querySelectorAll`) on page load and then, every time a label is added to the dom. This can also mess up any mouse event listeners added to labels or the dom in general as you use `Event#preventDefault` to avoid double clicking on browsers that don't have this bug. Finally, using the `click` event would be better, since it would have the same interaction as the intended action. Other than that, this is best answer so far.

Comment: @nickzoum i have updated the code to fix your `preventDefault()` problem, so it works by checking if the browser has changed it if not change it, after 150 ms fast enough for the user to not notice it, and slow enough that the browser will have acted intime if it's going to do what it's supposed to. is that better?

Answer (score 1):

No. This looks like a firefox bug and not an issue with your code. I don't believe there is a css workaround for this behavior.

You may be able to report it to Mozilla and get the issue fixed, but I wouldn't rely on that. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/home

For a potential workaround I would suggested triggering the event on mouseup instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without javascript, when you click the label that has its "for" value the same as an inputs "id" value then the input gets clicked, but this is not consistent amongst browsers.

If a browser does follow the above, then your javascript click event will cancel out the effect, which ends up doing nothing.

## A solution

To have consistency amongst browsers you could adopt a different strategy:
Onload dynamically change all the attribute 'for' for 'data-for', so it nulls the original browser affect. Then you can apply your click event to each label.

```
var replaceLabelFor = function () {
    var $labels = document.querySelectorAll('label');
    var arrLabels = Array.prototype.slice.call($labels);
    arrLabels.forEach(function (item) {
      var att = document.createAttribute('data-for');
      att.value = String(this.for);
      item.setAttributeNode(att);
      item.removeAttribute('for')
    });
}

var applyMyLabelClick() {
  document.querySelector("label").addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked label");
  });
}

// x-browser handle onload
document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
  if(document.readyState === "complete"){
    document.detachEvent("onreadystatechange", arguments.callee);
    replaceLabelFor();
    applyMyLabelClick();
  }
});
```

Comment: `document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",` I'm just integeged how comes you went with that and not `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",`?

Comment: It was just a method I saw which is a bit more x-browser. Choose which ever you prefer.

Answer (score -2):

Attaching the event to the document and targeting the element you require in there ought to sort this issue.

​    $(document).on('click', '.item', function(event) {});

From reading on this topic in the past, it’s down to Firefox understanding your action as an attempt to drag the element however, since user select is none, it just prevents the default behaviour.

This is based on fairly limited knowledge but it seems to be a known bug/quirk and there is a few articles floating around supporting this.

Comment: I explicitly said in the question `without using JavaScript event listeners`.

Comment: @nickzoum since this is a known bug in Firefox, I think you’re out of luck.